# Intersectionality status

Tags: conditionals

I understand the concepts under the term where oppressed or minority group seek equality or recognition.  However the unification of a number of groups must lead to a position of strength and dominance and therefore the original description would no longer apply.  When the oppressed become the majority or have the power to dictate policy, what happens to the group or groups that have been displaced?  Are they subjected to a period of oppression and victimhood, must they repent to the new reigning forces or seek there own or multiple oppressed status?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about the English language at all.

Comment: Maybe the mods should move this to the Politics StackExchange site?

Comment: What country does this question apply to?

Answer (score 1):

*For those who may read this question and need clarification*: Intersectionality is a term describing when an individual is marginalized (implicitly,explicitly and/or systematically) on more than one "axis" or mode. For example, a woman may be "oppressed" (marginalized more likely if we're talking about someone in a developed country) simply for being a woman. She may be even more marginalized if she is a person of color, thus an "intersection." Of course if such a segment of the population gained enough power, they wouldn't be marginalized anymore and intersectionality wouldn't apply to them.

This doesn't necessarily mean those that were "displaced" from their positions of power or privilege would be worse off though. What would happen to the disenfranchised (if they are indeed thus) is more left to the realm of politics or perhaps philosophy. Perhaps those in power would make fairer and more equitable laws? You are framing the theoretical outcome in an a priori way.